# scanf and keeping char as an integer

Tags: char, int, scanf

I just can't get it.
Char is an integer, right? So I can do

```
int var;
scanf("%d", &var);
I:[65]
printf("%c", var);
o:[A].
```

Why is then wrog to do:

```
char var;
scanf("%d", &var);
I:[A]
printf("%d", var)
O:[-1236778]
```

Comment: Because `%d` expects an `int*`, not a `char*`?

Comment: but characters are kept as integers?

Comment: `char` **is** an integer data type, but that **doesn't** mean that it's the same as an `int`.

Comment: So my question is: what's the difference, except size of?

Comment: Well, that's a pretty major difference in this context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `scanf()`

```
scanf("%d", &var);
```

the `scanf()` parsed the print directive `%d`.   This implies that the argument  `&var` is expected to be the address to an `int`.  Instead the address to a `char` was given.  The size of an `int` is certainly larger than the size of a `char`.  As `scanf()` attempts to place an `int` size amount into a place meant only for a 'char', strange things can happen for scanf() may place data is places it should not.  Trying to put 10 pounds of potatoes in a 5 pound sack.

Further - it appears doubtful that `scanf("%d", &var);` successfully read the input "A".  `scanf()` would see the `A`, and since it is not a digit, would give up scanning for textual input that meets an `int` definition.  Thus your `scanf("%d", &var)` likely returned a value of `0` and thus did not place *anything* in `var`.  Saving your bacon, for if it did, it would place data in space it should not.

The final `printf("%d", var)` is then simply printing out the `var` which has never been set, so you get *whatever* happened to be in char.  `-1236778` seems unlikely.  I suspect that the post does not match the code nor the input/output in some small pace.

Comment: Thanks,with your comment and some additional reading on data types and scanf function it feels like i got it. Finally:)